# Datatable is null when I try to insert to the datagridview

Tags: c#

I am trying to enter data to the datagridview but I get the following error that my dt2 is null, I don't know what the problem is, I did it this way because it previously notified me of some data-bound

```cs
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2 = dgvCliente.DataSource as DataTable;

DataRow row = dt2.NewRow();

row[0] = txtNumeroIdentificacion.Text.ToString();
row[1] = txtCliente.Text.ToString();
dt2.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Use the debugger to see what type is `dgvCliente.DataSource` because it is not a `DataTable`, maybe it's a `BindingSource `. Also, the first line is useless, don't initialize a new instance of `DataTable` if you don't use that instance but just override it with another instance(or `null` in this case) in the next line.

Comment: Did you ever set an initial value for the DataSource property?. If you never set anything into it then do not expect to get anything out of it